# Misformatted parenthesis in exponent

Tags: bug, mathjax

The formula

```
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x)^{\cot x} & =\lim_{x \to 0} ((1+(\cos x-1))^{\frac{1}{\cos x -1}})^{(\cos x -1)\cot x}\\\\
…
```

renders like this with the HTML-CSS or Common HTML renderers:
[image: formula rendering with misplaced parenthesis]

My bug report is about the close parenthesis at the end of the exponent.  It should be to the right of $\cos x -1$, not overlapping the $-1$.

This with Firefox 114.0.2 (64-bit), Mozilla Firefox Snap for Ubuntu, canonical-002 - 1.0.

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x)^{\cot x} & =\lim_{x \to 0} ((1+(\cos x-1))^{\frac{1}{\cos x -1}})^{(\cos x -1)\cot x}\\\\
\end{align}$$

[Original post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4729841/25554)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Firefox 115.0.2 + Windows 10. Renders as expected.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem too with Windows 10 Firefox, nor Crome (Version $114.0.5735.199$ (Offizieller Build) ($64$-Bit)) :

Answer (score 1):

It looks OK to me:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x)^{\cot x} & =\lim_{x \to 0} ((1+(\cos x-1))^{\frac{1}{\cos x -1}})^{(\cos x -1)\cot x}\\\\
…
\end{align}
$$
with HTML-CSS in Safari 14.1.2

> [image]