# Malformatted parentheses

Tags: bug, mathjax

**Update**: StackExchange is still using MathJax v2.7.5, while the current release is v3.2 and has corrected some of this sort of rendering error.  So this report may not be of interest to anyone.

---

[Davide Cervone says this is a good place to report MathJax rendering bugs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/left-and-right-vs-bigl-and-bigr#comment23470_6561), so I am doing that.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1309167/25554 contains the formula

> `|x-x_0|<(n+1) \left | \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi_{n-1})}{f^{(n+1)}(\xi_n)} \right |`

which rendered as

> [image: bad rendering 1]

My browser is:

> Firefox 119.0.1 (64-bit)
> Mozilla Firefox Snap for Ubuntu
> canonical-002 - 1.0

The browser zoom was set to 100%.  My MathJax math renderer is "common HTML".

The formula renders differently, but still  incorrectly (for me) in this post itself, where the browser zoom is set to 120% and the renderer is "HTML-CSS":
$|x-x_0|<(n+1) \left | \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi_{n-1})}{f^{(n+1)}(\xi_n)} \right |$

It looks like this:

> [image: bad rendering 2]

[A seemingly related earlier bug report](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35838/misformatted-parenthesis-in-exponent). I still see the rendering problems I described there.

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This
`|x-x_0|<(n+1) \left | \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi_{n-1})}{f^{(n+1)}(\xi_n)} \right |`
renders for me as
[image]

Safari 14.1.2, renderer HTML-CSS